# Daterangepicker moment() returns numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, unix-timestamp, daterangepicker

I have a .cshtml with a daterangepicker.js implemented in it. This page gets the date range (to date, from date) from a parent page via ViewBag. The code is the following:

```
var _FromDate;
var _EndDate;

$(function () {
    var from1 = '@ViewBag.from_date';
    var from = from1.split("-");
    var f = new Date(from[0], from[1] - 1, from[2]);

    var to1 = '@ViewBag.to_date';
    var to = to1.split("-");
    var t = new Date(to[0], to[1] - 1, to[2]);

    var start = (f.getFullYear() + '-' + pad((f.getMonth() + 1), 2) + '-' + pad(f.getDate(), 2));
    var end = (t.getFullYear() + '-' + pad((t.getMonth() + 1), 2) + '-' + pad(t.getDate(), 2));

    function cb(start, end) {

        $('#reportrange span').html(start + ' . ' + end);
        var dateRange = $('#reportrange span').html();
        _FromDate = dateRange.substring(0, dateRange.indexOf('.'));
        _EndDate = dateRange.substring(dateRange.indexOf('.') + 1);
    };

    function pad(str, max) {
        str = str.toString();
        return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        locale: { format: "YYYY-MM-DD" },
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
```

Now here's the problem: when running the page, the daterangepicker returns the date as 
[a string of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yInna.png)

What is the cause of the problem? I went through the code step by step and I can't find the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you console.log the values of  **from1** and **to1** and paste it here, just right after their respective declaration ...

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan here you go: from1 shows 2017-09-10 and to1 shows 2017-09-10 (because in the previous page I chose 'Today' so it's showing the same values for both from1 and to1

Comment: Its all good. Its just ` $('#reportrange span').html(start + ' . ' + end);` the **start** and **end** are converted a unix timestamp (ms) .

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan ok then how do I make it display the date normally?

Comment: posted it as an answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got some unnecessary code, I did a rewite plunk https://embed.plnkr.co/G3xxp0HWPOoFYuF8u2qd/

```
 /* global variables to store your dates ..*/
var _FromDate;
var _EndDate;

$(function () {
  var _format = "YYYY-MM-DD";
  var start = moment('@ViewBag.from_date', _format); 
  var end = moment('@ViewBag.from_date', _format);

  /* update your display summary and your local variables... */
  function cb(start, end) {
    /* 
      storing the moment object. If case you post these values over to a server, defaulr ajax transforms into ISOstring.
      But in case it doesn't, your should  _FromDate = start.toISOString() or if u have a sppecific format start.format('{your format}') 
    */
    _FromDate = start;
    _EndDate = end;
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format(_format) + ' - ' + end.format(_format));
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    locale: { format: _format },
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

Comment: i added the code but now an error is appearing in my codebehind: Error converting data type nvarchar to date. I'm sending the _FromDate and _EndDate variables to the codebehind to fetch data from a stored procedure.

Comment: `_FromDate = start.format(_format)` BTW, did mention it in the comment ...